# Async Return on Sever Message to Client

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, callback

I have a number of clients that send objects to server1 using Post requests which in turn get sent to server2 using sockets.

Server1 Processes a post requst message from client converts to serverMessage. SeverMessage is sent asynchronously. it listens continuously for response messages that can come in any order but will have their id to identify them.

How do i send a response back to the original thread once Server1 has processed the correct MessageId

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your architecture correctly, You have a gateway or something like a service locator between your client and your business service provider and also the communication between these two servers is async. So you want to send back the procced request from the business service provider to the middle server. If this is your architecture I can recommend two solutions may be been useful:
**1. Keep the state in business service provider**:
keep the result of any request in some safe place (DB or Memory based on your business) in business service provider and implement a service to accept **messageId** and send back the result, Then considering to a meaningful period of time in your service broker (server1) you can ask for the result
 **2. Make a full duplex communication:**
You can also provide a service endpoint in server1 and once any process finished in server2 it can send the result for server1 through the endpoint

Comment: Yes that is the correct architecture.
My plan was to follow your answer 1. Once the message is processed by my Middle Gateway Server a database will be updated. The post thread that initiated the process can poll the db for the message up to 30seconds.
The full duplex communication was the part i was unsure how to implement.